# How to add background-color on background-image?

Tags: html, css

Css here...

```
background-image: url("image/login-background-image.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

I want background-color up-side of background-image.

Comment: Please share the expected output, some more details would also be nice!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

Works on all major browsers - tested on chrome, ie, firefox and edge.

```css
body {
background-image: 
  linear-gradient(rgba(46, 49, 65, 0.8), rgba(46, 49, 65, 0.8)),     
  url("https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/647/snowy-mountain-1378865.jpg");
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope the below CSS works for you...

background: #ff0000 url("image/login-background-image.png");

If not, Kindly share the expected output and both HTML and CSS

Comment: it's good to test code before posting

Comment: @TemaniAfif May I know the reason for down voting my answer!

Comment: And may I know why you are accusing me for downvoting your answer? you don't know and you cannot know who downvoted your anwser so please don't accuse the first person you see around.

Comment: @TemaniAfif : I am not accusing you Temani.. It helps me to improvise my problem solving skill if I missed to provide the appropriate answer.. By the way you have mentioned a comment saying "it's good to test code before posting". So I thought you would help me to understand if I did any mistakes on it.

Comment: testing your code will help you understand ... see what your code will produce and you will know what is the issue